# How to stop UITableView.reloadData() to interfere with setting UITableView.contentOffset

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

A `UIViewController` contains a `UITableView`. Once the VC becomes visible I need to call `UITableView.reloadData()` to make sure the table data is in sync with my model. At the same time I would like to use `UITableView.contenOffset = xy" to scroll the TableView to show specific data when becoming visible.

While this works in same cases, most of the time this **does not work at the same time**. It seems that `UITableView.reloadData()` tries to preserve the current scroll position and thus interferes with the manual scrolling using `UITableView.contenOffset`.

How to solve this?

---

#### Details:

- A Parent View Controller presents one of two possible Child View Controllers.

  - One Child View Controller is a *viewer* which shows data of some entity, e.g. data of a employee like name, address, phone numbers, etc.
  - The other Child View Controller is an *editor* which allows to updated the details of an emplyee object.
  - Both Child View Controllers use a UITableView to present the data
- Assume the TableView on the `ViewVC` is currently scrolled to the *address* section.
- When switching to edit mode the `EditVC` need to updated its TableView in order to show the now selected employeed. Additionally the TableView of the `EditVC` should also be scrolled to show the *address* section.

Code:

```
var scrollOnViewWillAppear = false;

override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)
    employee = loadData

    if (isViewLoaded) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.contentOffset = getOffsetShowingTheSameDataAsInViewerVC()

        // Result is the same when using scrollRectToVisible as proposend in the comments 
        // tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: getOffsetShowingTheSameDataAsInViewerVC(), width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    } else {
        scrollOnViewWillAppear = true
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if (scrollOnViewWillAppear) {
        tableView.contentOffset = getOffsetShowingTheSameDataAsInViewerVC()
    }
}
```

As described this does not work since the reload overlaps with the manual scrolling.

Delaying the scrolling using `DispatchQueue.main.async` does not solve the problem. Additionally when using this delay in `viewWillAppear` the UITableView appears with the old scroll pos for a short moment and is this updated to the new content offset. This looks bad.

I found other posts which proposed to use `tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()` directly after `tableView.reloadData()` to prevent the TableView from performing its own scrolling actions to keep the same content offset.

**So: How to solve this?**

---

I would need something like this:

- Reload the TableView in `EditVC` before the VC becomes visible
- Wait for the TableView to reload is data (and maintaining the scroll position)
- Updating the scroll position manually, still **before** the VC became visible
- Let VC become visible to show the TableView to the user scrolled to the correct position.

Comment: did you try to move your code to "didAppear"/"didMove". sometimes it is just a timing issue....

Comment: @Chris This would scroll the TableView after it became visible and thus produce the same glitch as delaying the scrolling to the next run loop.

Comment: ok, and did you try it with "scrolltorect" instead of setting contentoffset?

Comment: @Chris The result is just the same. I have updated the question to include this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until `tableView.reloadData()` finishes and set the content offset after that:

```
tableView.reloadData {
    self.tableView.contentOffset = getOffsetShowingTheSameDataAsInViewerVC()
}

extension UITableView {
    func reloadData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
            self.reloadData()
        }, completion: { _ in
            completion()
        })
    }
}
```